# Gorm and associations

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to figure out how to load associations with `gorm`. The documentation is not that great.

I have to models:

```
type Account struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name          string `gorm:"column:name;unique_index;not null;size:255"`
    AccountTypeID uint   `gorm:"not null"`
    UserID        uint   `gorm:"not null"`
    AccountType   accounttypes.AccountType
}
```

and

```
type AccountType struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"column:name;unique_index;not null;size:255"`
    Type string `gorm:"column:type;unique_index;not null;size:255"`
}
```

So every `Account` has a `Account Type` associated with it.

When I try loading the data via:

```
func GetAccounts(userId uint) ([]Account, error) {
    db := common.GetDB()
    var model []Account
    db.LogMode(true)
    err := db.Model(&Account{}).Where("accounts.user_id =?", userId).Related(&accounttypes.AccountType{}, "AccountTypes").Error
    return model, err
}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Could someone please explain how to do this properly the 'gorm way'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clause.Associations` as documented: https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload-All

> `clause.Associations` can work with `Preload` similar like `Select`
> when creating/updating, you can use it to `Preload` all associations

Note:

> `clause.Associations` won’t preload nested associations, but you can
> use it with [Nested Preloading](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#nested_preloading) together

So, I haven't tested, but maybe you need something like this:

```
var userAccounts []Account
err := db.Where("accounts.user_id =?", userId).Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&userAccounts).Error
```

And the `Where`case could be `Where(&Account{UserID: userId})`

---

`clause.Associations` can use for preload all associations. If you want to preload one item, there is [`Preload(Item)`](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload) way. In your case: `Preload("AccountType")`

```
db.Where(&Account{UserID: userId}).Preload("AccountType").Find(&userAccounts).Error
```